# Having trouble with a multi-line graph with double nesting and a rollup of one of the columns I grouped by

Tags: d3.js, nested

I'm new to d3.js, and we have been requested to graph a multi-line chart. The data looks something like this:[image]

The goal is to group by year then by Math.floor(average_rating) and then get the counts of each average_rating(after being rounded down). The resulting graph should look something like this:
[image]

I've gotten as far as nesting the data using the two keys(year and average rating) then doing a .length on leaves to get the counts of each rating in each year 2015-2019(I filtered the data to  just those years). However, I am thoroughly confused on how to get the lines on there. I've been trying for two days but without much progress. My nest looks like this:
[image]

The code for my nest is as such:
[image]
I'm honestly not sure what to do and any help would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code you use to do the rollups?

Comment: I've added my code for the nest. I apologize that it's a screenshot instead of actual lines. My computer kept freezing up when I tried to paste and format the code on stack for some odd reason.